# Mongo db (jenssegers) connection error with laravel

Tags: mongodb, laravel

I am using laravel 5.6 with mongo db. Laravel is install successfully but when i install jessenger https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb it shows me error, You can see attached image.
i have also used php_mongo.dll  https://github.com/maryo/php-5.5-windows-extensions/tree/master/php_mongo-1.4.5-vc11-x86  but still showing error.
I need help to setup mongo db.

[attached link is error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXAyl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Got solution. Your php_mongodb.dll file should be compatible with php version.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the package like this:

```
composer require jenssegers/mongodb --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Comment: saurav please answer my above question. Thanks